# Build ROS completely from source code?

Tags: ros, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm looking for some tutorial about ROS building by checking out source from repository, not by rosinstall.
Is there any one who compiles ROS completely from source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32184/build-ros-completely-from-source-code?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosinstall **does** check out repositories and compiles code from source, it's just a convenient tool to check out everything at once:

http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall

If you don't want to use rosinstall, you can just download the rosinstall file, open it, and check out all the repositories defined in there yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4